# Google autofill on firstname dont work if big ul is present ...?

Tags: html, autofill

I have a very strange bug, i use the autofill on an firstname input like :

```
<input autocomplete="given-name" type="text">
```

On the same page is present an "ul" with a lot of "li" (its a country selector).
With 200 "li" the autofill dont work in the input, with 175 "li" the autofill work ...
There is absolutly no link between the "ul" and the input ...

here is the code :

```
<form>
<input autocomplete="given-name" type="text" id="fname">
<ul>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="ZA"><span>Afrique du Sud</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="AX"><span>Aland Islands</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="AL"><span>Albanie</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="DZ"><span>Algeria</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="AD"><span>Andorra</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="AO"><span>Angola</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="AI"><span>Anguilla</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="AQ"><span>Antarctica</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="AG"><span>Antigua and Barbuda</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="SA"><span>Arabie saoudite</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="AR"><span>Argentina</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="AM"><span>Armenia</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="AW"><span>Aruba</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="AU"><span>Australia</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="AT"><span>Austria</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="AZ"><span>Azerbaijan</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="BS"><span>Bahamas</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="BH"><span>Bahrain</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="BD"><span>Bangladesh</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="SV"><span>El Salvador</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="AE"><span>Émirats arabes unis</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="GQ"><span>Equatorial Guinea</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="ER"><span>Eritrea</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="ES"><span>Espagne</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="EE"><span>Estonia</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="US"><span>États-Unis</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="ET"><span>Ethiopia</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="FK"><span>Falkland Islands</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="FO"><span>Faroe Islands</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="FJ"><span>Fiji</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="FI"><span>Finland</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="FR"><span>France</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="GF"><span>French Guiana</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="PF"><span>French Polynesia</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="TF"><span>French Southern Territories</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="GA"><span>Gabon</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="GM"><span>Gambia</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="GE"><span>Georgia</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="GS"><span>Géorgie du Sud-et-les Iles Sandwich du Sud</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="DE"><span>Germany</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="GH"><span>Ghana</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="GI"><span>Gibraltar</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="GR"><span>Greece</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="GL"><span>Greenland</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="GD"><span>Grenada</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="GP"><span>Guadeloupe</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="GU"><span>Guam</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="GT"><span>Guatemala</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="GG"><span>Guernsey</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="GN"><span>Guinea</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="GW"><span>Guinea-Bissau</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="GY"><span>Guyana</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="HT"><span>Haiti</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="HM"><span>Heard Island and McDonald Islands</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="HN"><span>Honduras</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="HK"><span>Hong Kong S.A.R., China</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="HU"><span>Hungary</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="IS"><span>Iceland</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="UM"><span>Iles mineures éloignées des États-Unis</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="SB"><span>Iles Salomon</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="TC"><span>Iles Turks-et-Caïcos</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="VI"><span>Iles Vierges des États-Unis</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="IN"><span>India</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="ID"><span>Indonesia</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="IR"><span>Iran</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="IQ"><span>Iraq</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="IE"><span>Ireland</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="IM"><span>Isle of Man</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="IL"><span>Israel</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="IT"><span>Italy</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="CI"><span>Ivory Coast</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="JM"><span>Jamaica</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="JP"><span>Japan</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="JE"><span>Jersey</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="JO"><span>Jordan</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="KZ"><span>Kazakhstan</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="KE"><span>Kenya</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="KI"><span>Kiribati</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="KW"><span>Kuwait</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="KG"><span>Kyrgyzstan</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="LA"><span>Laos</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="LV"><span>Latvia</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="LB"><span>Lebanon</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="LS"><span>Lesotho</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="LR"><span>Liberia</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="LY"><span>Libya</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="LI"><span>Liechtenstein</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="LT"><span>Lithuania</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="LU"><span>Luxembourg</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="MO"><span>Macao S.A.R., China</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="MK"><span>Macedonia</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="MG"><span>Madagascar</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="MW"><span>Malawi</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="MY"><span>Malaysia</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="MV"><span>Maldives</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="ML"><span>Mali</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="MT"><span>Malta</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="MH"><span>Marshall Islands</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="MQ"><span>Martinique</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="MR"><span>Mauritania</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="MU"><span>Mauritius</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="YT"><span>Mayotte</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="MX"><span>Mexico</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="FM"><span>Micronesia</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="MD"><span>Moldova</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="MC"><span>Monaco</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="MN"><span>Mongolia</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="ME"><span>Montenegro</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="MS"><span>Montserrat</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="MA"><span>Morocco</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="MZ"><span>Mozambique</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="MM"><span>Myanmar</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="NA"><span>Namibia</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="NR"><span>Nauru</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="NP"><span>Nepal</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="NL"><span>Netherlands</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="AN"><span>Netherlands Antilles</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="NC"><span>New Caledonia</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="NZ"><span>New Zealand</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="NI"><span>Nicaragua</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="NE"><span>Niger</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="NG"><span>Nigeria</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="NU"><span>Niue</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="NF"><span>Norfolk Island</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="MP"><span>Northern Mariana Islands</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="NO"><span>Norway</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="OM"><span>Oman</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="UG"><span>Ouganda</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="PK"><span>Pakistan</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="PW"><span>Palau</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="PS"><span>Palestinian Territory</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="PA"><span>Panama</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="PG"><span>Papua New Guinea</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="PY"><span>Paraguay</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="PE"><span>Peru</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="PH"><span>Philippines</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="PN"><span>Pitcairn</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="PL"><span>Poland</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="PT"><span>Portugal</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="PR"><span>Puerto Rico</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="QA"><span>Qatar</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="RE"><span>Reunion</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="RO"><span>Romania</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="GB"><span>Royaume-Uni</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="RU"><span>Russia</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="RW"><span>Rwanda</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="EH"><span>Sahara occidental</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="SM"><span>Saint-Marin</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="SX"><span>Saint-Martin</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="BL"><span>Saint Barthélemy</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="SH"><span>Saint Helena</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="KN"><span>Saint Kitts and Nevis</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="LC"><span>Saint Lucia</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="MF"><span>Saint Martin (French part)</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="PM"><span>Saint Pierre and Miquelon</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="VC"><span>Saint Vincent and the Grenadines</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="WS"><span>Samoa</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="AS"><span>Samoa américaines</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="ST"><span>Sao Tomé-et-Principe</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="SN"><span>Senegal</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="RS"><span>Serbie</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="SC"><span>Seychelles</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="SL"><span>Sierra Leone</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="SG"><span>Singapour</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="SK"><span>Slovakie</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="SI"><span>Slovénie</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="SO"><span>Somalie</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="SD"><span>Soudan</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="SS"><span>Soudan du Sud</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="LK"><span>Sri Lanka</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="SE"><span>Suède</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="CH"><span>Suisse</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="SR"><span>Suriname</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="SJ"><span>Svalbard et Jan Mayen</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="SZ"><span>Swaziland</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="SY"><span>Syrie</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="TW"><span>Taiwan</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="TJ"><span>Tajikistan</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="TZ"><span>Tanzanie</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="TH"><span>Thailande</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="TL"><span>Timor oriental</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="TG"><span>Togo</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="TK"><span>Tokelau</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="TO"><span>Tonga</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="TT"><span>Trinité-et-Tobago</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="TN"><span>Tunisie</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="TM"><span>Turkmenistan</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="TR"><span>Turquie</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="TV"><span>Tuvalu</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="UA"><span>Ukraine</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="UY"><span>Uruguay</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="UZ"><span>Uzbekistan</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="VU"><span>Vanuatu</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="VA"><span>Vatican</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="VE"><span>Venezuela</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="VN"><span>Vietnam</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="WF"><span>Wallis-et-Futuna</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="YE"><span>Yemen</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="ZM"><span>Zambie</span></label></li>
   <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="ZW"><span>Zimbabwe</span></label></li>
</ul>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you please provide html code for form where you have mentioned first_name?

Comment: The input was at the end , i move it at the top of form

Answer (score 0):

For such long list of countries, use `select` rather than radio button. A searchable `select` will further help the user.

Comment: Yes this is a select rewrite by a multiple select script